Chat API's spaces.messages.list 's response doesn't contain "threadReply" bool flag
When I fetch a specific messages using chat api's spaces.messages.get endpoint, its response contains a threadReply boolean flag to indicate if its a reply or first message. Apparently, it doesn't come with the messages in response to spaces.messages.list. Am I missing something or is requesting a get for each message in list's response the only way to get this ?

I found Identity whether a message is a reply of another message, which is similar to your question. The post didn't seem to have progressed much because the user who reported it deleted their account. I would suggest that you submit another request in the Google Issue Tracker regarding this matter.
